# Ruby Twitter gem

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems

-- UPDATE --

Ok its fixed. This is what I did. remove all ruby and rubygems completely. then install ruby1.9.1-full and rubygems1.9.1 then install the twitter gem.

Hi guys,

I am having trouble working with the Twitter gem. I am using ruby 1.8.7

After installing when I try to run a simple script I get this error

ruby twitter.rb 
./twitter.rb:5: uninitialized constant Twitter (NameError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
    from twitter.rb:2

I running this on a Ubuntu box. I checked with gem -list and I see the Twitter (1.1.0) is listed there.

this is the code I am trying to run

```
require "rubygems"
require 'twitter'


puts Twitter.user_timeline("test").first.text
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I just experienced this issue and it turned out that rubygems was telling bundler to install the wrong version of the gem.  I explicitly set the version in bundler and ran bundle update and got it working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it only works with Ruby 1.9 If you want to use twitter gem try version 0.9 with Ruby 1.8.x

Comment: ok I uninstalled ruby 1.8.7 install 1.9.2 also install rubygems 1.9.2 and now I get this error                                                  twitter.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- twitter (LoadError)
 from twitter.rb:2:in `<main>'

Comment: I used pik to install ruby1.9.2 over my earlier ruby 1.8.7. I did not need to update system gems. 
What I can think right now, is since you have upgraded to ruby 1.9.2, you have to re-issue the command "gem install twitter"
since the gem was installed under ruby-1.8.7 earlier and now you have installed ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > require 'twitter'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > puts Twitter.user_timeline("test").first.text 
TExES Pedagogy and Professional Responsibilities EC-12 Teacher Certification Test Prep Study Guid… - by Sharon A Wynne http://amzn.to/f3kF74
 => nil
```

which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: right sorry i forgot to put that ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]

Answer (score 0):

gouravtiwari21's comment seems to fix the problem, but it's wrong to suggest that the twitter gem requires 0.9.0 if you want to run it using Ruby 1.8.x.

You can check out the version compatibility here:
http://travis-ci.org/#!/jnunemaker/twitter

It shows the twitter gem working with Ruby installs as low as 1.8.7.

For me, it was an issue with having the correct dependent gems, as well as the correct versions.

Here's how I got it working:

I ran:

```
sudo gem list
```

And compared the versions of specific gems with what I found here:
https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter/blob/master/HISTORY.md (I simply searched for the word 'dependency' to see which versions twitter cared about.

I also found this diff:
https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter/commit/ac8114c1f6ba2da20c2267d3133252c2ffc6b6a3

And I compared the gems listed there with what I had installed, and I just made sure my system lined up with what I was seeing in the version notes.  Oftentimes what happened is that I had multiple versions of a gem, and for some reason, the lower version was taking precedence.

I'm not sure why I still have to add

```
gem 'twitter', '1.7.1'
```

to my Gemfile, but alas, that's the last step required in order to get this stuff working.

Don't forget to restart your server, and you should be good!

Comment: Thanks i will try this if i ever run into the same problem again.